# Reflection shader (orginated from XNA 10 years ago) doesn't work - Model is just black?

Tags: shaders, monogame, reflection-rendering

can anyone help me with this one.

I'm creating a 3D game. For my game, i have created a lot of 3D objects. Im everything works as intended so far, but I'm trying to implement a "Chrome Reflection" material i need to use for some of the objects. I can find a lot of XNA samples ,and Unity samples, none of them seems to work with Monogame.

I am absolutely no expert in Shaders (HLSL), please if anyone can give me a hint :)

Here is the shader code:

```
#if OPENGL
#define SV_POSITION POSITION
#define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_3_0
#define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_3_0
#else
#define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_4_0_level_9_1
#define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_4_0_level_9_1
#endif

float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;
float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;

float4 TintColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float3 CameraPosition;

Texture2D SkyboxTexture;
samplerCUBE SkyboxSampler = sampler_state
{
  texture = <SkyboxTexture>;
  magfilter = LINEAR;
  minfilter = LINEAR;
  mipfilter = LINEAR;
  AddressU = Mirror;
  AddressV = Mirror;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
  float4 Position : POSITION0;
  float4 Normal : NORMAL0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
  float4 Position : POSITION0;
  float3 Reflection : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
  VertexShaderOutput output;

  float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
  float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
  output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

  float4 VertexPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
  float3 ViewDirection = CameraPosition - VertexPosition;

  float3 Normal = normalize(mul(input.Normal, WorldInverseTranspose));
  output.Reflection = reflect(-normalize(ViewDirection), normalize(Normal));

  return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    return TintColor * texCUBE(SkyboxSampler, normalize(input.Reflection));
}

technique Reflection
{
  pass Pass1
  {
    VertexShader = compile VS_SHADERMODEL VertexShaderFunction();
    PixelShader = compile PS_SHADERMODEL PixelShaderFunction();
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the model is just "black" :(
(Normal rendering using BasicEffect)
[image: Normal Rendering]

(Rendering using the reflection shader)
[image: With the reflection shader]